# How can I correctly route in index.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

Im creating a blog project using React (MERN) and when rendering this happens:

[image]

My code on index.js is this:

```
import React from 'react';
import  ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { HashRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
// import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

import Signin from './components/Signin';
import Signup from './components/Signup';
import Home from './components/Home';
import HeaderApp from './components/HeaderApp';

ReactDOM.render(<HeaderApp/>,document.getElementById('header'));
ReactDOM.render(
<HashRouter>
    <div>
      <Route exact path='/' Component={Signin}/>
    </div>
</HashRouter>, document.getElementById('root'))

reportWebVitals();
```

Also for note, im using two elements to display in the *index.html* file, hence the two renders:

[image]

Update: Added the code of the Signin Component

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `<Routes>` tag

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <HashRouter basename="/app">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" /> {/*  Renders at /#/app/ */}
      </Routes>
    </HashRouter>
  );
}
```

Your code should be:

```
<HashRouter>
    <div>
     <Routes>
       <Route exact path='/' Component={Signin}/>
     </Routes>  
    </div>
</HashRouter>
```

More info in:
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/hash-router

Comment: I now added the Routes tag, however a new error appeared: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: Add an image of how do you have your component, maybe the error is there

Comment: And how are you importing the `Signup` component? I mean in the file you are using

Comment: My mistake, i showed the wrong component instead of Signin. I updated the post (Also tried adding the route to signup to try it out and it works fine. Somehow Signin inst working despite having the same structure)

Comment: But how are you importing the `Signin` in another file? By seeing the code I think the error of the first comment it's due another file

Comment: By using ```import Signin from './components/Signin';``` . Is it not correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Are you still getting the error: `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`?

Comment: i still get the error

Comment: I fixed the error, apparently ```<Postlist/>``` was incomplete and had no code. This created the issue. I guessed it by isolating parts of the code that worked and only the line with Postlist wasnt working. Thanks you for your help